# How to read ul-lists and send the result back to java?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsf

I have the following xhtml-file:

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            template="/templates/default.xhtml">
<ui:define name="head">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/partitioning.css"/>
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="content">
    <ui:include src="partials/navigationbar.xhtml"/>

    <div class="row container">
        <h1>Verteilung Analysis 2a für Informatiker ...</h1>

        <div id="listContainer">
            <ul class="small-block-grid-2 middel-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-2">
                <ui:repeat value="#{groupController.allGroups}" var="group">
                    <li>
                        <section class="tutorium">
                            <f:param name="class_id" value="#{group.id}"/>
                            <h1>#{group.weekdayString}, #{group.timeStart} - #{group.timeEnd} Uhr</h1>

                            <p class="subheader">#{group.leader.name}</p>

                            <div>
                                <!--<h:outputText value="ABC" rendered="#{group}"/>-->
                                <ul id="memberList" class="connectedSortable" value-id="#{group.id}">
                                    <ui:repeat value="#{group.groupMembers}" var="user">
                                        <li value-id="#{user.id}" class="sortable-item">#{user.name}</li>
                                    </ui:repeat>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    </li>
                </ui:repeat>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Verteilung speichern"/>
            <a href="#" class="button secondary">Abbrechen</a>
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Verteilung exportieren"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="deleteDialog" class="reveal-modal small" data-reveal="">
        <h2>Vorsicht</h2>

        <p class="error">In jedem Tutorium muss mindestens ein Teilnehmer sein. Sollen leere Tutorien gelöscht
            werden?</p>
        <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>

</ui:define>
<ui:define name="scripts">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/vendor/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            document.getElementById("listContainer")
            var $lists = $("#listContainer").find(".connectedSortable");
            $lists.sortable({
                connectWith: $lists,
                placeholder: 'placeholder'
            });
        });


        var data = {};
        $("ul.memberList").each(function() {
            $(this).data("value-id");
            $(this).find("li").each(function() {

            })
        })

    </script>
</ui:define>
```

In this case you are able to manipulate those lists using drag and drop. They get filled with data from a SQL-database. However, after changing some entries with drag and drop, you should be able to save those changes to the database in the backend.

But I don´t know how I am supposed to do that. My idea was to somehow iterate those list, save them in a Array and save the belonging list-items. Something like this:

```
            var data = {};
        $("ul.memberList").each(function() {
            $(this).data("value-id");
            $(this).find("li").each(function() {

            })
        })
```

But in fact, I don´t have any idea how this works with JavaScript, how you can save that to a var and especially how to send it to Java. I tried to figure it out by Google but I hardly could find anything. So I would be very grateful if somebody could help me out. And I am very sorry for my bad English. ;)

EDIT:
We´re using "Mojarra".

The first step is that those "ul" get filled with a variable number of information from my database (every ul gets an value-id). Each ul´s "li" gets a value-id, too. Now the aim is to retrieve this values for example as an array or something in order to return them to Java where this information gets processed. My problem is that I don´t know how I can iterate those uls and lis, save them and return it to Java. I guess I have to call  my java-method in my JavaScript which iterates through and draws out all data.

Afterwards - on Java-side - I have to work with what JavaScript gives me back. But I guess I can figure that out by myself.

I just tried this:

```
function test() {
            var data = new Array();
            $("ul.memberList").each(function() {
                var buffer = $(this).data("value-id").toString();
                var members = new Array();
                $(this).find("li").each(function() {
                    members.push(this.data("value-id").toString());
                });
                data.push(members.join(".")+","+buffer);
            });
            alert(data.join(";"));
        }
```

But the alert is just empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Primefaces with JSF then its easy to communicate with JSF Managedbean from Javascript using `p:remoteCommand` component mentioned in this [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975746/how-to-call-managed-bean-methods-with-parameters-via-javascript/18976408#18976408).

But If you are using a plain JSF then you have use hidden fields and submit them from javascript.

```
<h:form id="ghostForm">
    <h:inputHidden id="hide1" value="#{managedBean.property1}"/>
    <h:inputHidden id="hide2" value="#{managedBean.property2}"/>
    ...
    ...
    <h:commandButton id="ghostSubmit"  action="#{managedBean.action}" />        
</h:form>
```

From your script its clear that you are using the JQuery so i'll also use the JQuery in script:

```
function fillUpAndSend(){
    $("#ghostForm\\:hide1").val("ValuetoBeSentforHide1");
    $("#ghostForm\\:hide2").val("ValuetoBeSentforHide2");
    ...
    ...
    $("#ghostForm\\:ghostSubmit").click();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I´m not sure if it is what I need. I´ll try to explain it more precisely.